# Figuring out whether my laptop has soldered or upgradeable RAM without opening it up?

Tags: memory, upgrade, sodimm, hp-spectre

I have a few questions that are all related to trying to figure out if my laptop has soldered or upgradable memory.

1. The memory section in Task Manager says **Slots: 2 of 2, Form Factor: SODIMM**. Likewise, `wmic memorychip get formfactor` returns 12 (twice), which also stands for SODIMM. So the question is, since SODIMM is a type of slot, does that confirm that the motherboard has two (upgradeable) SODIMM slots instead of soldered RAM chips? Edit: What I'm trying to ask is: does SODIMM necessarily mean not soldered? Or is there such a thing as a soldered SODIMM?
2. On the other hand, `wmic memorychip get devicelocator` returns "**Bottom - on board**" (twice). What does this mean?
3. Finally, my motherboard is HP 863E, so if someone has confirmed information about what sort of RAM (soldered or upgradeable) that contains, I would appreciate it since this would directly answer my main question.

Edit: I already have looked online for this information about my particular device, but information from various sources is a bit conflicting. One reason in particular I'm confused is that `wmic memorychip get partnumber` returns **H5AN8G6NCJR-VKC**, which an online search reveals is an SK Hynix Ram *IC*, not a SODIMM RAM *module*, so if someone knows the answer to specifically my first two questions, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You cannot tell from software whether the Memory is soldered in or not. My ThinkPad X1 has memory soldered in and only can only be upgraded at purchase. You need to look at your HP machine specfications to determine how much memory and whether there is a socket for you to upgrade.

Comment: @John The HP Machine Specifications are not completely clear about this. However, I believe it should be possible to answer whether SODIMM always means a slot or could be soldered as well, since that would bring me closer to an answer, as well as if anyone knows how to interpret "bottom - on board".

Comment: I got a "build" document from Lenovo for my X1 at purchase time that detailed everything. This is what you need. Multi purpose specs may not help you.

Answer (score 1):

The tools offered by  [Kingston](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory) or [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/store/advisor?cm_re=homepage-_-hero-_-combobox-selector-btn) will give you details about memory and expandability

Answer (score 1):

Question, marked "Solved" on HP support forum about RAM upgrade:

> I have an HP Spectre x360 ... Motherboard : 863E ...

Answer

> You can install 2 x 16 GB of memory in your notebook, and definitely
> get DDR4-2666 because your notebook's processor should run the memory
> at the full 2666 MHz speed and not bridge to 2400 MHz as it does with
> most of the Intel 8th gen processors.
>
> Adding faster memory than 2666 MHz would only bridge to 2666 MHz, so
> no performance benefit would be derived.
>
> The parts list for your notebook's product number shows a single 8 GB
> memory chip came with the unit.

[HP Forum thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Re-Ram-Upgrades/td-p/7800781)

Comment: I actually have seen this forum thread, but I also have seen information to the contrary, so it's a bit confusing. That's why I'm trying to understand what "onboard" means as returned by `wmic get devicelocator`.

Comment: What do you get from `wmic memorychip get removable` ?

Comment: I get "removable".

Comment: From what I have seen in forums topics about laptops with soldered RAM, that comes back as just a blank if the RAM is not removable. Also try `wmic memorychip get formfactor`

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that answers my core question. I wasn't aware that this particular property could be retrieved. If you could mention this in the form of an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For HP laptops you often can find a "maintenance and service guide" document, which is intended for "authorized service centers" and describes exact procedures to disassemble a computer, replace or add components, together with a component HP product numbers. [This](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06155404) is an example of such manual.

You can find it with, you know, google search " maintenance service guide" or like, just be as verbose as you can for model name, include a "generation" and so on. Just "hp spectre" is not enough (and with that you likely to find this example I linked to).

From such manual it must be clear if your computer has upgradable RAM or not, and also which RAM it supports.